# Search the content of a PDF file uploaded in media library

Tags: content-search

I'm using sitecore 9.3.

I have a case where i have some content files (ex: PDF files) uploaded to sitecore media library and I have a search box component.

I need to configure my search box scope to search the content of those media library files. So if i wrote a search keyword,in the search box, that is included in the content of those uploaded PDF files, then i need to return this files somehow in the search results.

According to this [Link](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/index-content-of-media-files.html), PDF files content is indexed by default in sitecore 9.3, but i'm not sure how to check these indexed content? and how to return its items in a search result.

Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same request before and following what I did:

1. Download and install PDF Ifilter on CM server, here is the link  http://download.adobe.com/pub/adobe/acrobat/win/9.x/PDFiFilter64installer.zip, after install please clear media cache + sitecore cache and restart IIS, then rebuild indexes.

[image]

2. Use Solr Admin to check media items are being indexed use something like:

[image]

3. Also make sure to inherit _Searchable base template in your media items templates, see the following screenshots:

Media items templates as example:

/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Versioned/Document

/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Document

Base template to inherit:

/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Search/Computed Fields/_Searchable

[image]

In Solr admin you should find the PDF item and the _Searchable field set to true in order to get it in your search results:
[image]

Comment: where is media cache and sitecore cahce located?

Comment: sitecore cache: websiteUrl/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx

media cache: media folder under websitePath\App_Data\MediaCache

Comment: i followed the steps but now the PDF files items appears in the search scope but nothing is returned in search results, any idea what i might be missing?

Comment: check if you are using the correct index (use browser network tab to find the request and the params used), check if you are using a suitable result template for media items,  I used Scriban to create a search result variant (https://sitecoreinfo.blogspot.com/2020/05/sitecore-xa-custom-search-results-using.html), also check the language of your search result interface (language/index mapping configured on the (/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings/Site Grouping/Site) more information (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/93/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/configure-sxa-indexing.html).

Comment: index is correct, language is correct . And in my variant definition i only added a "varianttext" just for testing.
When i include any template rather than the "PDF / File" templates, it's returned in the search results.Only the files template items are not returned although they appear in the scope

Comment: If you used solr admin, query your index, do you see the items (pdfs)? are they searchable (_searchable=true)? do you have any facets/filters in your search results?

Comment: yes the PDF items are indexed in solr and the "_searchable = true"
and also the "sxacontent_txm" has all the file content indexed. And no i don't have any facets or filters in my search result component. xD

Comment: what is varianttext you mentioned above? what field or value are you expecting to be displayed in the search results?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108719/discussion-between-amiraelewady-and-mohammed-syam).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.
After some investigation, turned out that the "Associated Media" and "Datasource search scope" fields on the site settings node (/sitecore/content/Tenant/MySite/Settings) was not including the media library, that's why all media files was excluded in search results. Updating those two fields to include the "Media Library" node, fixed the problem and media files are returned in search results.

Comment: Glad you got that sorted out!